# Problems exporting meshes to Unity 5

Tags: unity, 3d, textures, models, materials

After creating a tree (Scots Pine) in SpeedTree Cinema v7.1.1 I exported it as a .FBX ascii file to Unity 5 and I encountered a problem; the leaf material, while viewing it in Unity 5, can only be seen when I view the tree from the top, but when I view the tree from the bottom or the side, the leaves dissapear, they're not visible anymore, but on the other side, I can view the leaves of the tree from any angle in SpeedTree Cinema v7.1.1.

I don't know if the problem is one of the following:

1. The way I export the tree (.FBX ascii)
2. The way the texture is saved (.tga, .jpg, .png)
3. The material settings (in SpeedTree or Unity)

So you can better understand, i'll show the following images:
*Description of images is below*

[image: Here are the setting of how I export the tree and you can also see the clearly see the leaves from all angles.]

[image: Here is my tree (the tall one, Scots Pine) and you can't see the leaves from underneath and the material displayed on the right belongs to the leaves of my tree (the tall one, Scots Pine). The tree to its side(the small one) is how I would like the leaves to look ( i didn't make the small tree).]

[image: In here you can see the leaves of my tree (tall one, Scots Pine) from the top, and next to my tree is another one (not my tree) which is how i would like my trees leaves to look. The material displayed on the right are from the small tree (not my tree).]

(Image 1.) Here are the setting of how I export the tree and you can also see the clearly see the leaves from all angles.

(Image 2.) Here is my tree (the tall one, Scots Pine) and you can't see the leaves from underneath and the material displayed on the right belongs to the leaves of my tree (the tall one, Scots Pine). The tree to its side(the small one) is how I would like the leaves to look ( i didn't make the small tree).

(Image 3.) In here you can see the leaves of my tree (tall one, Scots Pine) from the top, and next to my tree is another one (not my tree) which is how i would like my trees leaves to look. The material displayed on the right are from the small tree (not my tree).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The problem is that there is only one copy of the leaves' triangles, which point up (the point order is clockwise viewed from above). You need to duplicate the triangles to point down as well. I'm not sure how to do this in your software.

Comment: @AaronFranke So you're saying that the leaves aren't double-sided ?

Comment: That's the only logical explanation.

Comment: @AaronFranke So, do you think that if I use a plane and apply the texture on it, that it would solve the problem ?

Comment: Could you try a double-sided shader?

Comment: @JesseWilliams I'd have to either make the shader myself or buy one in the asset store. The only thing that works is the Soft Occlusion Leaves shader, but the quality really takes hit, a big one. But thanks for the help, be sure to tell me any other ideas you have.